# Música na página do site

Tags: html, áudio, reprodutor-de-video

Gostaria de saber uma maneira de colocar música rodando em background quando a página do site é carregada de uma forma automática sem necessidade do usuário utilizar um player para a música começar, procurei na documentação do *W3School* e o exemplo citado lá é o código abaixo:

```
<audio controls>
  <source src="horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

Gostaria que fosse de uma forma automática quando carregasse a página a música começasse a tocar.

Answer (score 1):

Para fazer com que o audio começa automaticamente basta utilizar o atributo `autoplay`. Se não quer que pareça um player basta retirar o atributo `controls`:

```
<audio autoplay> <!--agora com autoplay e sem controls-->
  <source src="horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  Your browser does not support the audio tag.
</audio>
```

Se quiser pode também utilizar o atributo `loop` para fazer com que a musica volte ao inicio quando terminar.

Exemplo a funcionar:

```html
<audio autoplay>
  <source src="https://freesound.org/data/previews/367/367496_4654185-lq.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  Your browser does not support the audio tag.
</audio>
```

[Documentação para a etiqueta `<audio>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio)

Comment: Então Isac, quando eu coloco esse código ele aparece um player, e também a música não toca nem clicando no play do player

Comment: @VinniciusGomes Veja a minha edição. Tem o ficheiro de audio indicado no `src` ? `horse.ogg` ou `horse.mp3` ?

Comment: Tem sim                                                                                             
                                                                                                          
  <source src="../assets/media/quiz.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="../assets/media/quiz.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">

Comment: @VinniciusGomes Veja como o exemplo na resposta funciona. Confirme se tem mesmo os arquivos, e se estão na pasta correta

Comment: Percebi que era algum erro em meu arquivo, pois o que você colocou ali funcionou. Obrigado Isac, boa noite.

Comment: @VinniciusGomes Sem problema, boa noite também.

Answer (score 0):

```js
//script
var x = document.getElementById("musica"); 
x.play();
```

```html
<!-- HTML-->
<audio id="musica">
  <source src="horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/Syntaxxx/bigger-picture.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```